# MPandroidChart - zoom in and out to fit values on Y axis only

Tags: android, view, mpandroidchart

I am working with the awsome MPandroidChart open-source library and i am populating the chart live from data i am receiving online, when populating the chart with new values,  I allow only a specific amount of x index to be visible, using "setVisibleXRange()" and "moveViewToX()" to slide the chart to the left of the screen, displaying only the last entries at a time.

this all works great but I want to achieve a situation where the view port is modified to fit exactly the highest and lowest visible values, same as "fitScreen()" but that modifies the Y axis only.
"zoomOut()" and "zoomIn()" are using relative inputs, same as "zoom()"
so i cannot use them based on my data.
what i need is a way to position the view on the Y axis so the it fits different ranges at each cycle, for example: 2 to 15 or -98 to 34 an so on.

does anyone have any ideas on how this could be done?
appreciate all answers.
@PhillJay

Comment: Please explain the down vote, i would be happy to rephrase the question or even delete it if it is inappropriate or if it has no value for any other user that might be running into the same issue

Comment: This is a bit old, but anyway: `setAxisMinimum` and `setAxisMaximum` would be what you needed, right?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Have you found the soultion? @ZivKesten

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit old, but to whom it may concern the answer is not about axis. What you need is modifying viewport:

```
private void autoScaleLineChart(@NonNull LineChart lineChart) {
    if (lineChart.getLineData() == null) return;

    float lowestVisibleX = lineChart.getLowestVisibleX();
    float highestVisibleX = lineChart.getHighestVisibleX();

    LineData chartData = lineChart.getLineData();
    chartData.calcMinMaxY(lowestVisibleX, highestVisibleX);
    //calculating offsets for axes to display correct labels
    lineChart.getXAxis().calculate(chartData.getXMin(), chartData.getXMax());
    calculateMinMaxForYAxis(lineChart, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    calculateMinMaxForYAxis(lineChart, YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
    //this is where the magic happens
    lineChart.calculateOffsets();
    //if nothing happens try adding
    //lineChart.invalidate();
}

private void calculateMinMaxForYAxis(@NonNull LineChart lineChart, @NonNull YAxis.AxisDependency axisDependency) {
    LineData chartData = lineChart.getLineData();
    YAxis yAxis = lineChart.getAxis(axisDependency);
    if (yAxis.isEnabled()) {
        float yMin = chartData.getYMin(axisDependency);
        float yMax = chartData.getYMax(axisDependency);
        yAxis.calculate(yMin, yMax);
    }
}
```

Also it might be helpful to read this: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer is not perfect, but *Yaxis* can fit the screen:

```
chart.getAxisLeft().setLabelCount(10, true);
chart.fitScreen();
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you read the [documentation of the YAxis](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis-(YLabels)).

Focus on the following methods:

- `setStartAtZero(...)`
- `setAxisMaxValue(...)` & `setAxisMinValue(...)`
- `setSpaceTop(...)`
- `setSpaceBottom(...)`

With some of those you should be able to restrict the visible area of the axis exactly to your needs.

Comment: I am sorry, it is not that i don't read the documentation, it is that i don't fully understand the method descriptions, it appears to me that this whole section in the doc relates to the Y labels and is not affecting the zoom in or out of the chart, can you please explain the function of those method? as i don't see how they can help me to dynamically zoom in and out according to my given values.